# Adding ManyToMany field data between models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer so any help will be greatly appreciated:)

I want to add a predefined list of objects from one model to another using ManyToMany field. However, I am not sure the best practices or how exactly to accomplish this.

For example:

```
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    BOOKS = (
        ('b1','Secret Life of Bees'),
        ('b2','Pride and Prejudice')
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=BOOKS)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Library(models.Model):
    librarian = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

```
#views.py
def create_library(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LibraryCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            library = form.save(commit=False)
            listOfBooks = request.POST.getlist('books')
            library.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = LibraryCreateForm()
    return render(request, 'create_library.html', {'form':form})
```

```
#forms.py
class LibraryCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Library
        fields = ['books']
```

```
#create_library.html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox" value="b1" name="books">
    <input type="checkbox" value="b2" name="books">
</form>
```

This isn't working for me, and I don't know how to fix it correctly.
To be more specific, I would like to essentially do the equivalent of this in python but with DJango:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.skills = [] 


class Skill:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


programmingSkillOne = Skill("C++")
programmingSkillTwo = Skill("Java")
programmingSkillThree = Skill("QML")

listOfSkills = []
listOfSkills.append(programmingSkillOne)
listOfSkills.append(programmingSkillTwo)
listOfSkills.append(programmingSkillThree)

personOne = Person("Stephanie")

personOne.skills = listOfSkills

personTwo = Person("Lizzy")
personTwo.skills.append(Skill("C++"))

people = [personOne, personTwo]

print ("\n")

for person in people:
    print(person.name + "'s skills are: \n")
    for s in person.skills:
        print(s.name)

    print("\n")
```

My issue is adding books to the library model based on what the user picks.
I have read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/ but am still struggling.

Comment: You need to call `form.save_m2m()` to save many-to-many data if you passed `commit=False` to `form.save` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Furhtermore the `value="b1"` part will not work, since that is not the primary key of a book.

Comment: Note that you can work with a widget to show checkboxes, there is no need to manually render that in the template.

Comment: @IainShelvington I should be calling form.save_m2m() after library.save() right? For some reason the data still isn't being saved.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem What am I supposed to put for the value instead then? An example would be really helpful!

Comment: @Nick: the primary key of the corresponding book.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, I think I am not sure how to do this. I thought 'b1' would be the  primary key of the corresponding book?

Comment: @Nick: no, that is the value for the `name`, but the `name` field is not the primary key. Since you did not specify one, Django took the liberty to add an `AutoField` with the name `id` that is the primary key.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think this is getting lost on me, and I really appreciate the help! So then, should I not be adding in value ="___"?
EDIT: I added in value="1", value="2", etc. This is what you meant I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone who gets stuck on this in the future: In your view function, you need to get or create the book object and save it to the associated library. You also need to remove books from the fields in the forms.

```
#views.py
...
        if form.is_valid():
            library = form.save()
            books = request.POST.getlist('books')
            for b in books:
                b = Book.objects.get_or_create(name=b)[0]
                b.save()
                library.books.add(b)
            return redirect('browse')
    else:
...
```

And you can also verify this works easily in your html with the following:

```
#create_library.html
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for book in booklist %}
        {{ book.get_name_display }}
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ book.name }}" name="books">
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```